# Using CoreImage on the GPU and UIActivityIndicator

Tags: ios, performance, core-animation, core-image

#### Background

I'm developing an iOS photo editing app extension.
Now that I've got my Core Image code working as expected, I'm turning my attention to performance improvements (it isn't fast, at least on the Simulator).

In order to keep the app responsive while my extension applies its filters (both the "preview" while editing and the final result when committing the edits), I'm rendering on a background queue.

At the same time, I am **presenting modally** a custom view controller that displays an **activity indicator view**, to inform the user that a lengthy process is in progress

[image]

*(this only for the preview render; for the final commit, Photos.app takes over and displays its own activity indicator view)*

#### The Problem

Reading through the Core Image Programming Guide, in the section "[Getting the Best Performance](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_performance/ci_performance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001185-CH10-SW2)", I came across this piece of advice:

> Avoid Core Animation animations while rendering CIImage objects with a GPU context.
>
> If you need to use both simultaneously, you can set up both to use the CPU.

This got me thinking; Doesn't UIKit, (and `UIActivityIndicatorView` in particular) use Core Animation?

Regarding the final render, I am considering using the CPU anyway: reportedly it seems to produce higher quality results, and the GPU has size constraints that might be easily overwhelmed by the full-size of the original images typically found in the Photos library.

**But for the screen-size, preview render I would prefer to use the GPU.**

I can begin rendering immediately *after* the modal view controller has been presented (and avoid overlapping the presentation transition), but the activity indicator needs to animate while the GPU render is in progress.

**How Can I Provide Animated Feedback While Applying CoreImage Filters to an Image on the GPU?**

---

Similar (but *not* duplicate, if I'm not wrong) question: [How do you run Core Animation and Core Image together on the CPU?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34867883/433373)

Comment: A few things. (1) DO NOT USE THE SIMULATOR FOR PERFORMANCE TESTING! I cannot stress this enough (obviously). It doesn't give you any kind of idea of things. (2) Stick to the GPU for CoreImage - which means using `GLKView` or `MLKView` for rendering a `CIImage`, and only use a `UIImage` when necessary. (3) Understand your view hierarchies and mixes. While - and I've done this - a GLKView renders a CIImage using the GPU, it actually is a subclass of `UIView` which is part of `UIKit`. There shouldn't be a problem adding a CPU-driven animation in a UIView as a subview of a GPU-driven GLKView.

Comment: @dfd Thank you. I am revisiting the WWDC videos on everything CoreImage since 2014 now, and clearing up a lot of misconceptions and misunderstandings. Your comment is quite timely and helpful.

Comment: @dfd In the end, the preview rendering is almost immediate even on an iPhone 5s, so I did away with the activity indicator altogether.

Comment: My experiences indicate that something that takes 5 seconds to render on the simulator takes a few MILLI-seconds on any iOS device. I'm sorry if my first point looked like I was "yelling" - I was only trying to stress something as, um, loudly as possible!